# Explanantion of this Regular expression

Tags: regex

This regular expression matched the content in between a `<` and  `>`:

`<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>`

but this can also be done by using this follwing expression `<([a-z]*|[A-Z]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)>`.

The expressions in square brackets in the first RE are not clear.

Could any one please explain its meaning ?

Comment: This expression check if quotes are balanced inside the tag.

Comment: The `[^"]*` notation means anything that isn't `"`. I don't think these expressions are equivalent, though. The second one is matching letters and numbers.

Comment: Remark : `<([a-z]*|[A-Z]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)>` only matches elements between `<` and `>` that are 'word characters' or 'decimals', so the 2 regex don't do the same. The first one will match for example `<"bla">` but the second one will not.

Comment: @polkduran Oh! ... I was actually testing them on html tags that is why I had thought they do the same thing! Thanks for pointing that out ...

Comment: The expression check if the tag isn't empty too. IMO `<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">]+)+>` will be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mechanically, the first regular expression matches any string between angle brackets (<, >), subject to the following restrictions:

1. A single quote or double quote (SDQ) must be eventually followed by a second single or double quote of the same type (SDQ).  For example, `<This "te>xt">` and `<This 'text'>` are valid, but `<This "text>` and `<This "text'>` are not.
2. A second quote in the first item may be immediately followed by any number of single or double quotes, and these are not subject to the restriction in (1).  For example, `<This "text"">` and `<This "text"'>` are valid, but `<This "text" ">` is not.

Let's break this expression down.  Suppose you start with the requirement that the string must match any non-quote characters between angle brackets.  This gives you:

```
<[^'">]+>
```

This is functionally equivalent to this, where `?:` represents a non-captured group:

```
<(?:[^'"]>)+>
```

Now suppose you want to then allow single and double quotes, provided that they are balanced. This extends the expression to:

```
<(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])+>
```

This new expression allows any combination of the following, in any order, between two angle brackets:

- Any number of characters between to double quotes
- Any number of characters between to single quotes
- A character that is not a closing bracket a quote

Finally, suppose you want to extend this expression further to allow any number of single or double quotes immediately following a quote group (items 1 and 2 above).  (Perhaps as an attempt to permit a form of escaping.)  This can be incorporated to the expression by adding `["']*` after both quote groups:

```
<(?:"[^"]*"["']*|'[^']*'["']*|[^'">])+>
```

This gives the final expression.  Note that this expression is different from `<([a-z]*|[A-Z]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)>` (which is equivalent to `<[a-zA-Z0-9]*)>`), since the latter does not allow quotes at all.

Answer (score 0):

`<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>` is:

```
    Sequence: match all of the followings in order
    <
    Repeat
        NonCapturingGroup
            OR: match either of the followings
                Sequence: match all of the followings in order
                    "
                    Repeat
                        AnyCharNotIn["]
                        zero or more times
                    "
                    Repeat
                        AnyCharIn['"]
                        zero or more times
                Sequence: match all of the followings in order
                    '
                    Repeat
                        AnyCharNotIn[']
                        zero or more times
                    '
                    Repeat
                        AnyCharIn['"]
                        zero or more times
            AnyCharNotIn[ ' " >]
        one or more times
    >
```

Comment: Have you done this by yourself? or do you have a tool to do this analysis?

Comment: It's fairly simple to just manually write the regex out in more verbose pseudocode, a tool isn't really even nessisary (although it could be helpful).